# How to calculate the number of box according to their position?

Tags: python, pygame

I'm developing a python memory based game and having a problem to find the number of box the user clicks, according of the position of the cursor.

I already have this:

```
number = ev.pos[y]//boxsize*numboxsx+ev.pos[x]//boxsize
```

(with this line I get what you can see on the left of the picture in red)

But I have to consider: `mx` and `my`, they are the margin, because the boxes are centered. (What I show in the right of the picture in green).

So, how can I modify the line to get the number of box with the margin?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to subtract the margins from the cursor position. Think of it as translating from absolute coordinates (where the cursor is on the screen) to relative coordinates (where the cursor is relative to your boxes).

```
relx, rely = ev.pos[x] - mx, ev.pos[y] - my
number = rely//boxsize*numboxsx + relx//boxsize
```

Comment: thanks!!!! i was trying to solve this for weeks and finally you save my life! thanks bro! your idea its working so good!!!

Answer (score 1):

A much better approach would be to use sprites, and sprite collision. If you will define your boxes, as sprites, you can then check if a sprite(your mouse) has collided with your box. 
The advantage of this approach is that you will not have to operate on coordinates, and in the future you can move, resize, or increase the amount of boxes on screen without code change on this side.